# Relative path not working in windows service

Tags: c#

I have a bit weird situation. In the `onstart` method of a windows service if I put following code:

```
File.AppendAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\TestFile.txt", "Started " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

it works and inside text file this is stored:

```
Started C:\Users\guser\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\FreeSpaceControlService\FreeSpaceControlService\bin\Debug\
```

The text file is created inside debug directory.

But if I use such code instead of the above(at the same place):

```
  File.AppendAllText("TestFile.txt", "Started");
```

The text file **is not** created in the same directory as above. Why it is not created in the same directory? (It seems it was created in WIndows/System32 now that I check it - are there two executables? Why did the first return Debug directory?)

and where you typically(in which path) store settings for windows service and logs?

Comment: The environmental variables in the window service is not the same as when you are logged in.  The owner of the service must be changed to run as a user instead of an admin.

Answer (score 4):

Because the [working directory of Windows services](https://stackoverflow.com/q/884963/87698) is `%WinDir%\System32`.

You can verify this for yourself:

```
File.AppendAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\TestFile.txt",
                   "My working directory is: " + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

> and where you typically(in which path) store settings for windows service and logs?

- Settings: In the Windows registry.
- Logs: In the Windows event log.
- Any other files your service might need: Somewhere below `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` (e.g. `C:\ProgramData\myService`). For more details, see the following question:
  [What is the significance of the ProgramData folder in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9518890/87698).

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is an old question, but I wanted to provide an answer in the case that it could be useful for someone else that stumbles upon this question and needs an answer.

I needed to figure out something similar, i.e. calling an executable from the directory that the service is installed in, the answers to this question were helpful:

[What directory does a Windows Service run in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884963/what-directory-does-a-windows-service-run-in)

Ultimately, it was not the accepted answer for that question that was useful, but a different answer. I used this code to access the directory that the service was installed in:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

A relative path is based on the 'Current directory',  `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` and `Environment.CurrentDirectory` are not necessarily  the same.

Comment: slight explanations what each other mean and how relate to windows services would be more appreciated

Comment: Yes, but it [all has been done before](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/370e35/basedirectory-vs-currentdirectory-in-C-Sharp/)