# fatal: bad numeric config value 'false[sendemail]' for 'http.sslverify': invalid unit

Tags: git

I've opened all git files with `git config --system -e` `git config --global -e` `git config --local -e`

And the faulty line cannot be found in any of them. If I write `git config -list` I see the faulty line: [image]

Where is it stored if it's not in local/global/system?

Answer (score 2):

Found it: [Why Git config list (total) is not the same as system + global + local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111522/why-git-config-list-total-is-not-the-same-as-system-global-local)

Apparently it's another gitconfig in C:\Users\All Users\Git and my faulty line was in there.